# Is there a mechanism for integration testing JAX-RS services without deploying (a la MockMVC)?

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, integration-testing, rest-assured, karate

I have successfully built no-deployment-needed integration test frameworks for Spring MVC REST services using Mock MVC.  I am struggling to do the same with JAX-RS services.

REST Assured looks promising, but it seems to require deployment.  The test suite  can start up a CXF server, but can it wire it up with a servlet container?

It seems that the unique value provided by Mock MVC is in its mock servlet container.  Does any other technology provide this.

The [JAX-RS testing page of the CXF documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAXRS+Testing#JAXRSTesting-MockingHTTPcontexts) provides a pattern for injecting a mock **HttpServletRequest** into a CXF invoker.  Which got me thinking ...

Spring MVC's mock servlet elements (**MockHttpServletRequest**, etc.) come from the **spring-test** module, is independent of Mock MVC.  Would we be able to inject these objects into a CXF invoker?  Or will this be a rabbit hole?

Has anyone come up with a solution to this problem?

---

.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Karate Spring Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642974/karate-spring-integration)

Answer (score 3):

Daniel - I'm the developer of [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) and something I've been experimenting with is to use a combination of Mockito and the Spring mocks for the HTTPServletRe**** to call a servlet directly and avoid having to boot an app-server.

Since Karate has this [swappable abstraction of an http-client](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/http/HttpClient.java), I was thinking of adding this option in the near future.

Just sharing in case it helps you with ideas, or if you want to compare notes. Feel free to open a thread on GitHub.

Update: I made very good progress on this - please look at [this thread](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/100#issuecomment-313902944) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you, Peter.  I am currently consulting a team whose productivity is compromised by the need to continually deploy services to WebSphere.  Your solution here would be huge.   

My client has a Testing Tools organization that is  currently evaluating several tools, including Karate and REST Assured.  I have informed the organization of your efforts toward providing this feature.  

I have opened [an issue on Karate in GitHub](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/100).

Comment: @DanielSteinberg acknowledged ! I'm going to take a look at the options.

Comment: @DanielSteinberg - I've updated the GitHub issue with a commit that has a full example (Jersey). Even if your env is not Jersey, you should be able to create a custom mock using the approach demonstrated. I'd like to get feedback from you and your team before releasing this into the next Karate version.