# Karate Spring Integration

Tags: java, karate

We have a Spring MVC application, Is it possible to integrate spring context in Karate ? .Say bind the SpringJunitRunner through the Karate runner. Or to lookup the bean by spring context ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything is possible in Karate because you can always use Java interop.

You can use the documentation of the servlet-mocking as a reference: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-mock-servlet

So you should be able to pass the context around as a config variable. Also I think there is a Spring helper to get access to an already running context (via Java) you can search for that also.